# Memory leak with objective-c on alloc

Tags: objective-c

When I use Instruments to find memory leaks, a leak is detected on

```
Horaires *jour;     
jour= [[Horaires alloc] init]; // memory leak reported here by Instruments
self.lundi = jour;
[jour release];
```

and I don't know why there is a leak at this point.

Does anyone can help me? Here's the code.

```
// HorairesCollection.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Horaires.h"

@interface HorairesCollection : NSObject < NSCopying > {
    Horaires *lundi;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Horaires *lundi;
-init;
-(void)dealloc;
@end


// HorairesCollection.m
#import "HorairesCollection.h"

@implementation HorairesCollection

@synthesize lundi;

-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone{
    HorairesCollection *another = [[HorairesCollection alloc] init];
    another.lundi = [lundi copyWithZone: zone];
    [another autorelease];
    return another;
}

-init{
    self = [super init];
    Horaires *jour;     
    jour= [[Horaires alloc] init]; // memory leak reported here by Instruments
    self.lundi = jour;
    [jour release];
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [lundi release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end


// Horaires.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Horaires : NSObject <NSCopying>{
    BOOL ferme;
    BOOL h24;
    NSString *h1;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL ferme;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL h24;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *h1;

-init;
-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone;
-(void)dealloc;

@end


// Horaires.m
#import "Horaires.h"
@implementation Horaires

-(BOOL) ferme {
    return ferme;
}

-(void)setFerme:(BOOL)bFerme{
    ferme = bFerme;
    if (ferme) {
        self.h1 = @"";
        self.h24 = NO;
    }
}

-(BOOL) h24 {
    return h24;
}

-(void)setH24:(BOOL)bH24{
    h24 = bH24;
    if (h24) {
        self.h1 = @"";
        self.ferme = NO;
    }
}

-(NSString *) h1 {
    return h1;
}

-(void)setH1:(NSString *)horaire{
    [horaire retain];
    [h1 release];
    h1 = horaire;
    if (![h1 isEqualToString:@""]) {
        self.h24 = NO;
        self.ferme = NO;
    }
}

-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone{
    Horaires *another = [[Horaires alloc] init];
    another.ferme = self.ferme;
    another.h24 = self.h24;
    another.h1 = self.h1;
    [another autorelease];
    return another;
}

-init{
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc {
    [h1 release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: In Horaires.m you are creating property for h1 and also writing its get use synthesis.

Answer (score 2):

You've set your property to retain and you alloc and release the variable, so from what I can see the code is okay and Instruments has given you a false warning.

I think your `copyWithZone:` might have a leak, though. `[lundi copyWithZone:]` will retain a copy of `lundi` but you never release it. So you need an extra release, something like this:

```
-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone{
    DefibHoraires *another = [[DefibHoraires alloc] init];
    Horaires* makeCopy = [lundi copyWithZone: zone];
    another.lundi = makeCopy;
    [makeCopy release];
    return another;
}
```

This is because `copy` and `alloc` both return retained object instances and you need to manually release them when you're finished with them. You did that correctly for your alloc'd objects but not the copy.

Comment: another.lundi is synthesized, [lundi copyWithZone:] is set to another.lundi. Why would there be a leak and how resolve it? I'm new to objective-c.

Comment: Because a copy is retained... I've revised my answer.

Comment: [autorelease] is a bug. copyWithZone: needs to return a *retained* object.

Comment: I knew for alloc but not copy. Thank you for that clarification.

Comment: @Eiko You're correct. I didn't spot that in the original code. I've edited my answer fixing that error as well.

Answer (score 0):

That `init` method looks ok, although it should be implemented (and typed) as

```
-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        ...
    }
    return self;
}
```

or a similar pattern.

Your copyWithZone implementations are wrong, they need to return a retained object, so do not autorelease the returned value. But you need to release your copy of `lundi`, because you are using the retaining setter.

```
-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone{
    DefibHoraires *another = [[DefibHoraires alloc] init];
    Horaires *lundiCopy = [lundi copyWithZone:zone];    
    another.lundi = lundiCopy;
    [lundiCopy release];
    return another;
}
```

I don't know why you return an instance of `DefibHoraires` here, shouldn't it be a `HorairesCollection`?

Maybe the wrong copyWithZone: method is responsible for the reported leak (it's a leak anyway).

One further note: It's a good defensive rule to use `(copy)` for `NSString` properties instead of `(retain)` to remove side effects when passing `NSMutableString` instead.

Comment: Oh, just *one more thing*: I tend to use English in my code all over and never looked back. ;-)

Comment: The static analyzer is also very good at spotting such problems.

Comment: Thanks for all. I'll modify my code. This is not DefibHoraires but HorairesCollection. I modify the code of my question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer but I do have some general comments:

1. In `copyWithZone:` you should use `allocWithZone:` (passing the same zone as a parameter) to allocate the object you are going to return.
2. `copyWithZone:` should return a retained object.  Don't autorelease it.
3. You are not supposed to use properties in init.  Your init should look something like:

   ```
   -init
   {
       self = [super init];
       if (self != nil)
       {
           lundi = [[Horaires alloc] init]; // assign the ivar directly
       }
       return self;
   }
   ```
4. In your `copyWithZone:` for HorairesCollection you have a leak.  It should look like:

   ```
   -(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone{
       DefibHoraires *another = [[DefibHoraires allocWithZone: zone] init];
       another.lundi = [[lundi copyWithZone: zone] autorelease];
       return another;
   }
   ```

Comment: For 3., if I use lundi instead of self.lundi, my app crashes

Comment: @Grunzig: you are over releasing it somewhere else then.